# JBoss: MySQL driver not found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

I'm developing web application using MySQL under JBoss 7.1.1.
I have followed one of the tutorials to install MySQL driver on my server. I created appropriate directories in which I have placed driver:

```
modules
|--com
   |--mysql
      |--main
         |--mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
         |--module.xml
```

My `module.xml` looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">  
  <resources>  
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"/>  
  </resources>  
  <dependencies>  
    <module name="javax.api"/>  
  </dependencies>  
</module>
```

I have also added datasource and driver in `standalone.xml`:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/my_db" pool-name="MySqlDS">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db</connection-url>
        <driver>com.mysql</driver>
        <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>root</user-name>
        </security>
        <statement>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Then and I try to inject it in my bean and use like that:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(StartupBean.class);

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/datasources/my_db")
    private DataSource ds;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("MySQL driver not found!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to found driver i get:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

I have also tried not to check for driver and just call `ds.getConnection()`. It does not couse any exception. But when i try to invoke method on my connection I get:
`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6.getSchema()`

And here is the question. What have I missed while configuring connection? DataSource is bind according to logs. I have tried also newer driver version (5.1.35-bin) but it didn't change anything. Version of my mysql db is 5.6.24.

Comment: have you tried to include the jdbc driver in your web-inf/lib folder?

Comment: Also if you are developing your application using eclipse or netbeans make sure you add the driver in your project's library

Comment: I'm using Intellij adn gradle to develop my app. WEB-INF of ear? Will try in a sec.

Comment: I've placed it in ear/lib directory. Now there is no `ClassNotFoundException`, but I'm still getting second error.